# An astounding identity: $\int_0^{\pi/2}\ln\lvert\sin(mx)\rvert\cdot \ln\lvert\sin(nx)\rvert\, dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

In [this question,](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2821112/integral-milking-does-anyone-else-do-this)  user Franklin Pezzuti Dyer gives the following surprising integral evaluation:

$$\int_0^{\pi/2}\ln \lvert\sin(mx)\rvert \cdot \ln \lvert\sin(nx)\rvert \, dx = \frac{\pi^3}{24} \frac{\gcd^2(m,n)}{mn}+\frac{\pi\ln^2(2)}{2}$$

I've verified this numerically for small values for $m,n$.  Is there a proof?  Also, can we generalize it to more factors in the integrand?

Comment: I don't have a proof, but I would find it even more aesthetical with $\frac{\gcd(m,n)}{\operatorname{lcm}(m,n)}$ instead of $\frac{\gcd^2(m,n)}{mn}$.

Comment: This will probably require a lot more thinking, but have you tried replacing the absolute value signs with $\sqrt{(\cdot)^2}$?

Comment: @ArnaudMortier You can edit if you like, but I think I prefer the original.

Comment: @FrankW That could be a good first step, sure.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Okay, I'll prove it for you.

Start with the following well-known identity:
$$\int_0^{\pi}\cos(mx)\cos(nx)dx=\frac{\pi}{2}\delta_{mn}\tag{1}$$
...where $m,n$ are positive integers. Recall also the well-known Fourier Series
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\cos(kx)}{k}=-\frac{\ln(2-2\cos(x))}{2}\tag{2}$$
Now, replace $m$ in $(1)$ with $mk$, where both $m,k$ are integers, and divide both sides by $k$ to get
$$\int_0^{\pi}\frac{\cos(kmx)}{k}\cos(nx)dx=\frac{\pi\delta_{(mk)n}}{2k}$$
Then sum both sides from $k=1$ to $\infty$ to get
$$-\frac{1}{2}\int_0^{\pi}\ln(2-2\cos(mx))\cos(nx)dx=\frac{\pi m}{2n}[m|n]$$
where the brackets on the $RHS$ are [Iverson Brackets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket). A bit more manipulation yields the equality
$$\int_0^{\pi}\ln\bigg(\frac{1-\cos(mx)}{2}\bigg)\cos(nx)dx=-\frac{\pi m}{n}[m|n]$$
Now, this time, replace $n$ with $nk$ and divide both sides by $k$. This yields
$$\int_0^{\pi}\ln\bigg(\frac{1-\cos(mx)}{2}\bigg)\frac{\cos(knx)}{k}dx=-\frac{\pi m}{k^2n}[m|kn]$$
Then sum from $k=1$ to $\infty$ to get
$$-\frac{1}{2}\int_0^{\pi}\ln\bigg(\frac{1-\cos(mx)}{2}\bigg)\ln(2-2\cos(nx))dx=-\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{\pi m}{k^2n}[m|kn]$$
Now notice the following about the series on the RHS. Due to the Iverson Bracket, the kth term is zero unless $m|kn$, or unless $k$ is divisible by $m/\gcd(m,n)$. Thus, we let $k=jm/\gcd(m,n)$ for the integers $j=1$ to $\infty$ and reindex the sum:
$$\begin{align}
-\frac{1}{2}\int_0^{\pi}\ln\bigg(\frac{1-\cos(mx)}{2}\bigg)\ln(2-2\cos(nx))dx
&=-\sum_{j=1}^{\infty} \frac{\pi m}{(jm/\gcd(m,n))^2n}\\
&=-\frac{\pi\gcd^2(m,n)}{mn}\sum_{j=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{j^2}\\
&=-\frac{\pi^3\gcd^2(m,n)}{6mn}\\
\end{align}$$
or
$$\int_0^{\pi}\ln\bigg(\frac{1-\cos(mx)}{2}\bigg)\ln(2-2\cos(nx))dx=\frac{\pi^3\gcd^2(m,n)}{3mn}\tag{3}$$
Then, by using the result
$$\int_0^{\pi}\ln(1-\cos(ax))=-\pi\ln(2)\tag{4}$$
for all positive integers $a$, and the trigonometric identity
$$\sin^2(x/2)=\frac{1-\cos(x)}{2}\tag{5}$$
and finally, a substitution $x\to 2x$, the result easily follows from $(3)$ :
$$\bbox[lightgray,5px]{\int_0^{\pi/2}\ln \lvert\sin(mx)\rvert \cdot \ln \lvert\sin(nx)\rvert \, dx = \frac{\pi^3}{24} \frac{\gcd^2(m,n)}{mn}+\frac{\pi\ln^2(2)}{2}}$$

Comment: Very, very nice!  I'll accept this later once I have a chance to go through it properly.

Comment: This looks good - a beautiful proof of a beautiful fact. Although, I believe you are missing a few factors of $\pi/2$.  I'll accept your answer after a couple days to see if others can provide alternate proofs.

Comment: What does the $\delta$ function mean at the end of equation $(1)$?$$\int\limits_0^{\pi}dx\,\cos mx\cos nx=\frac {\pi}2\color{blue}{\delta_{mn}}$$

Comment: @FrankW.,This is the [Kronecker delta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_delta), equal to $1$ if $m=n$ and $0$ otherwise.

Comment: This isn't quite relevant to the question, but using the same technique in the linked question, I get$$\int\limits_0^{1}dt\,\frac {t^a(1-t)^b}{z-t^s(1-t)^k}=\sum\limits_{n\geq0}\frac {\Gamma(sn+a+1)\Gamma(kn+b+1)}{z^{n+1}\Gamma(a+b+n(s+k)+2)}$$which comes from the beta function and taking the sum from $n=0$ to $\infty$. It looks kinda promising to me...

Answer (score 11):

Though, I think the Fourier series approach is the cleaner approach for this integral, I'd like to present a somewhat unique alternative method.
This integral may be evaluated by exploiting symmetry and the following multiple-angle identity:
\begin{equation}
\sin(mx)=2^{m-1}\prod_{k=0}^{m-1}\sin\left(x+\frac{\pi k}{m}\right)
\end{equation}
Your integral is equal to $\frac{1}{2}I(m,n)$ where
\begin{equation}
I(m,n)=\int_0^{\pi}\ln|\sin(mx)|\cdot\ln|\sin(nx)|dx
\end{equation}

First, suppose than $m,n$ are coprime. We see that
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
I(1,n)&=\int_0^{\pi}\ln|\sin(x)|\cdot\ln|\sin(nx)|dx\\
&=\int_0^{\pi}\ln|\sin(mx)|\cdot\ln|\sin(mnx)|dx\\
\end{split}
\end{equation}
since the integrand has period $\pi$. Applying the multiple-angle formula for $\sin$ gives us that
\begin{equation}
I(1,n)=\sum_{k=0}^{m-1}\int_0^{\pi}\ln|\sin(mx)|\cdot\ln|\sin(nx+\pi k/m)|dx+ (m-1)\ln(2)\int_0^{\pi}\ln|\sin(mx)|dx
\end{equation}
Since $n,m$ are coprime, then the map $k\mapsto nk$ is an automorphism on $\mathbb{Z}/m$, meaning that
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
I(1,n)&=\sum_{k=0}^{m-1}\int_0^{\pi}\ln|\sin(mx)|\cdot\ln|\sin(nx+\pi nk/m)|dx \\
&\qquad\qquad + (m-1)\ln(2)\int_0^{\pi}\ln|\sin(mx)|dx\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{m-1}\int_0^{\pi}\ln|\sin(m[x+\pi k/m])|\cdot\ln|\sin(n[x+\pi k/m])|dx \\
&\qquad\qquad+(m-1)\ln(2)\int_0^{\pi}\ln|\sin(mx)|dx\\
\end{split}
\end{equation}
Again, since the integrands have period $\pi$ we may simplify
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
I(1,n)&=\sum_{k=0}^{m-1}\int_0^{\pi}\ln|\sin(mx)|\cdot\ln|\sin(nx)|dx+(m-1)\ln(2)\int_0^{\pi}\ln|\sin(x)|dx\\
&=mI(m,n)+(m-1)\ln(2)J\\
\end{split}
\end{equation}
where
\begin{equation}
J=\int_0^{\pi}\ln(\sin(x))dx
\end{equation}
Noting that $I(1,n)=I(n,1)$ and applying the above identity twice gives us that
\begin{equation}
I(m,n)=\frac{1}{mn}[I(1,1)+\ln(2)J]-\ln(2)J
\end{equation}

Now, in the case where $m,n$ are not coprime, then $\frac{m}{\gcd(m,n)},\frac{n}{\gcd(m,n)}$ are coprime, so by the periodicity of the integrand,
\begin{equation}
I(m,n)=I\left(\frac{m}{\gcd(m,n)},\frac{n}{\gcd(m,n)}\right)=\frac{\gcd^2(m,n)}{mn}[I(1,1)+\ln(2)J]-\ln(2)J
\end{equation}

Finally, $I(1,1)$ and $J$ are somewhat famous integrals which may be evaluated in a few different ways. [This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/37865/833331) shows that
\begin{equation}
J=-\pi\ln(2)
\end{equation}
using an elementary method, and in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4370228/833331) I use a complex-analytic method to show that
\begin{equation}
I(1,1)=\pi\ln^2(2)+\frac{\pi^3}{12}
\end{equation}
Putting these facts together, we have that
\begin{equation}
I(m,n)=\frac{\pi^3}{12}\frac{\gcd^2(m,n)}{mn}+\pi\ln^2(2)
\end{equation}
In other words, the original integral is given by
\begin{equation}
\boxed{\int_0^{\pi/2}\ln|\sin(mx)|\cdot\ln|\sin(nx)|dx=
\frac{\pi^3}{24}\frac{\gcd^2(m,n)}{mn}+\frac{\pi\ln^2(2)}{2}}
\end{equation}
which I think is a really beautiful result.

Answer (score 4):

A generalization of this integral is $$\small \int_{0}^{\pi} \ln \left(1-2 e^{- \phi} \cos (mx) + e^{- 2\phi} \right) \ln \left( 1-2 e^{- \lambda} \cos(nx) +e^{-2 \lambda}\right) \, \mathrm dx=    \frac{2\pi \gcd^{2} (m,n) \operatorname{Li}_{2} \left(\exp \left(- \, \frac{m\lambda +n \phi}{\gcd(m,n)}  \right) \right)}{mn} , $$ where $\operatorname{Li}_{2}(-)$ is the dillogarithm, $m$ and $n$ are positive integers, and $\phi, \lambda \ge 0$.

To prove this result, we'll use the Fourier series $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{e^{- k \phi} \cos(k \theta)}{k} = - \frac{1}{2} \, \ln \left(1-2 e^{- \phi} \cos(\theta) +e^{- 2 \phi} \right),$$ which can be derived by extracting the real part of the identity $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{\left(e^{-\phi}e^{i \theta}\right)^{k}}{k} = - \ln \left(1-e^{- \phi} e^{i \theta} \right). $$

We get

$$ \begin{align} &\int_{0}^{\pi} \ln \left(1-2 e^{- \phi} \cos (mx) + e^{- 2\phi} \right) \ln \left( 1-2 e^{- \lambda} \cos(nx) +e^{-2 \lambda}\right) \, \mathrm dx \\&=  4 \int_{0}^{\pi} \sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\frac{e^{- j \phi}\cos(jm x)}{j} \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-k \lambda }\cos(kn x)}{k} \mathrm d x \\ &= 4 \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{e^{- j \phi} e^{- k \lambda}}{jk} \int_{0}^{\pi} \cos(j m x) \cos(kn x) \, \mathrm d x \\ &= 2 \pi \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{e^{- j \phi} e^{- k \lambda}}{jk} \, \delta_{jm, kn} \\ &= 2 \pi \sum_{p=1}^{\infty} \frac{mn  }{p \operatorname{lcm}(m,n) p \operatorname{lcm}(m,n)} \, \exp \left(-\frac{p \operatorname{lcm}(m,n)}{m} \phi
- \frac{p\operatorname{lcm}(m,n)}{n} \lambda \right)   \\ &=  \frac{2 \pi \gcd^{2}(m,n)}{mn} \, \sum_{p=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{p^{2}} \, \exp \left(- p \, \frac{m\lambda +n \phi }{\gcd(m,n)} \right) \\ &=  \frac{2 \pi \gcd^{2}(m,n)}{mn} \, \operatorname{Li}_{2} \left(\exp \left(- \, \frac{m \lambda+n \phi}{\gcd(m,n)}  \right) \right). \end{align}$$

When the value of the integral is very small, Wolfram Alpha sometimes incorrectly says that the value of the integral is zero.

For $\phi=0$ and  $\lambda =0$,  we have $$ \begin{align}  &\int_{0}^{\pi} \ln \left(2-2 \cos(mx) \right) \ln \left(2-2 \cos(nx)\right) \, \mathrm dx \\ &= \int_{0}^{\pi} \ln \left(4 \  \frac{1-\cos(mx)}{2} \right) \ln \left(4 \ \frac{1+ \cos(nx)}{2} \right) \, \mathrm dx \\ &= \small \pi \ln^{2}(4) +  \ln(4) \left( \int_{0}^{\pi} \ln\left(\frac{1- \cos(mx)}{2} \right) \, \mathrm dx +  \int_{0}^{\pi} \ln \left(\frac{1- \cos(nx)}{2} \right) \, \mathrm dx \right) \\ &+  \small \int_{0}^{\pi} \ln \left(\frac{1- \cos(mx)}{2} \right) \ln \left(\frac{1-\cos(nx)}{2} \right) \, \mathrm dx  \\ &\overset{(1)}{=}  \small \pi \ln^{2}(4) + \ln(4) \left(-2 \pi \ln(2) -2 \pi \ln(2) \right)+ 2 \int_{0}^{\pi/2} \ln \left(\frac{1- \cos(2mt)}{2} \right) \ln \left(\frac{1-\cos(2nt)}{2} \right) \, \mathrm dt   \\&= \color{red}{-4 \pi \ln^{2}(2) +8 \int_{0}^{\pi/2} \ln |\sin(mt)| \ln |\sin(nt) |  \, \mathrm dt} \\ & = \frac{2 \pi \gcd^{2}(m,n)}{mn} \, \operatorname{Li}_{2} (1) \\ &= \frac{2 \pi \gcd^{2}(m,n)}{mn} \, \zeta(2) \\ &=  \frac{\pi^{3}}{3}  \frac{\gcd^{2}(m,n)}{mn}. \end{align}$$

---

$(1)$

For an positive integer $m$, $$ \begin{align} \int_{0}^{\pi} \ln \left(\frac{1-\cos(mx)}{2} \right) \, \mathrm dx &= \frac{1}{m} \int_{0}^{m \pi} \ln \left(\frac{1-\cos(u)}{2} \right) \, \mathrm du   \\ &= \frac{1}{m} \sum_{k=0}^{m-1} \int_{k \pi}^{(k+1) \pi} \ln \left(\frac{1-\cos(u)}{2} \right) \, \mathrm du  \\ &= \frac{1}{m} \sum_{k=0}^{m-1} \int_{0}^{\pi} \ln \left(\frac{1 -(-1)^{k} \cos(v)}{2} \right) \, \mathrm dv \\ &= \frac{1}{m} \sum_{k=0}^{m-1} \int_{0}^{\pi} \ln \left(\frac{1 - \cos(v)}{2} \right) \, \mathrm dv  \\ &= \int_{0}^{\pi} \ln \left(\frac{1 - \cos(v)}{2} \right) \, \mathrm dv \\ &=  \int_{0}^{\pi } \ln \left(\sin^{2}\left(\frac{u}{2}\right) \right) \, \mathrm dv \\ &= 4 \int_{0}^{\pi/2} \ln \left(\sin (v) \right) \, \mathrm dv \\ &= -2 \pi \ln(2) . \end{align}$$

---

I was going to use $|r| \le 1$ and  $|s| \le 1$ instead of $e^{- \theta}$ and $e^{- \lambda}$, but I chose the later because it looked cleaner.

Comment: Nice generalization. It's nice to see this question getting additional attention.