# How do you prove that $\ln(x) = \int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-t}-e^{-xt}}{t}$?

Tags: integration, limits, logarithms, improper-integrals, special-functions

I got the following result using the technique ["Integral Milking"](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2821112/integral-milking):

$$\ln(x) = \int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-t}-e^{-xt}}{t} dt= \lim_{n\to0}\left(\operatorname{Ei}(-xn)-\operatorname{Ei}(-n)\right)$$

for $x > 0$. So, I have a proof of it the result, but now I would like to know how to prove starting with either the integral or the limit. I'm not that familiar with the exponenential integral $\operatorname{Ei}(x)$, so my attempts were pretty bad (I'm not so familiar with the technique, but I'm still going to try to differentiate under the integral sign). Personally I have never seen an integral representation of the natural logarithm like this before, and I can't find it anywhere (e.g. [here](https://functions.wolfram.com/ElementaryFunctions/Log/07/)), but [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=lim%20n-%3E0%20Ei%28-xn%29-Ei%28-n%29) directly gets the limit right.

**Question:** How do you prove the the integral (or limit) is equal to $\ln(x)$ by starting with the integral (and not using e.g. integral milking)?

Comment: Hint: Differentiate the integral with respect to $x$.

Comment: @Gary Thanks, was just about to try that.

Comment: Frullani's integral ?

Comment: @Mister.Expandead Oh wow, that's amazing. Looking at the Wikipedia page reveals quickly that my case is just a specific one, the one that turns into $\ln(x)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fastest way to prove this is using Frullani's theorem, as you've seen in the comments, but you can also use a double integral to quickly solve this problem (which is one method how Frullani's theorem is proven).
$$I=\int_0^{\infty} \frac{e^{-t}-e^{-tx}}{t} \; dt = \int_0^{\infty} \frac{1}{t}\int_{1}^{x} te^{-tw} \; dw \; dt$$
Where $w$ and $t$ are dummy variables.  Now switch the order of integration:
$$I=\int_1^x \int_0^{\infty} \frac{1}{t} \cdot te^{-tw} \; dt \; dw= \int_1^x \int_0^{\infty} e^{-tw} \; dw \; dt\int_1^x \frac{1}{w} \; dw = \boxed{\ln{x}}$$

You can generalize this to the $\int_0^{\infty} \frac{f(ax)-f(bx)}{x} \; dx$.  Following these steps, you should see that the generalized integral is just $$[f(\infty)-f(0)] \ln{\left(\frac{b}{a}\right)}$$

Answer (score 1):

Well, we have the following integral:

$$\mathcal{I}_\text{n}\left(\alpha,\beta\right):=\int_0^\infty\frac{\exp\left(-\alpha x\right)-\exp\left(-\beta x\right)}{x^\text{n}}\space\text{d}x\tag1$$

Using the [lineairy of the integral](https://handwiki.org/wiki/Linearity_of_integration#:%7E:text=In%20calculus%2C%20the%20integral%20of,known%20as%20linearity%20of%20integration.), we can write:

$$\mathcal{I}_\text{n}\left(\alpha,\beta\right)=\underbrace{\int_0^\infty\frac{\exp\left(-\alpha x\right)}{x^\text{n}}\space\text{d}x}_{=\space\text{I}_\text{n}\left(\alpha\right)}-\int_0^\infty\frac{\exp\left(-\beta x\right)}{x^\text{n}}\space\text{d}x\tag2$$

Now, we look at $\text{I}$. Using [rules for exponents](https://www.mesacc.edu/%7Escotz47781/mat120/notes/exponents/review/review.html#:%7E:text=Only%20move%20the%20negative%20exponents,base%20and%20add%20the%20powers.&text=%2C%20this%20says%20that%20to%20divide,base%20and%20subtract%20the%20powers.):

$$\text{I}_\text{n}\left(\alpha\right)=\int_0^\infty x^{-\text{n}}\exp\left(-\alpha x\right)\space\text{d}x\tag3$$

Now, looking at the [definition of the Laplace transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform#Formal_definition) we can observe:

$$\text{I}_\text{n}\left(\alpha\right)=\mathcal{L}_x\left[x^{-\text{n}}\right]_{\left(\alpha\right)}\tag4$$

Using the [table of selected Laplace transforms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform#Table_of_selected_Laplace_transforms), we can see:

$$\text{I}_\text{n}\left(\alpha\right)=\frac{\Gamma\left(1-\text{n}\right)}{\alpha^{1-\text{n}}}\tag5$$

Now, we have your original integral:

$$\mathcal{I}_\text{n}\left(\alpha,\beta\right)=\text{I}_\text{n}\left(\alpha\right)-\text{I}_\text{n}\left(\beta\right)=\frac{\Gamma\left(1-\text{n}\right)}{\alpha^{1-\text{n}}}-\frac{\Gamma\left(1-\text{n}\right)}{\beta^{1-\text{n}}}=\Gamma\left(1-\text{n}\right)\left(\alpha^{\text{n}-1}-\beta^{\text{n}-1}\right)\tag6$$

> I let you prove:
>
> $$\mathcal{I}_1\left(\alpha,\beta\right)=\lim_{\text{n}\to1}\mathcal{I}_\text{n}\left(\alpha,\beta\right)=\ln\left(\beta\right)-\ln\left(\alpha\right)$$

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer Jan. I marked Ty.'s answer as the "accepted answer" for now, since I feel like he had a little "easier" solution, but depending on the response from the community I might change the accepted answer.